# my JS program isn't recognizing my jQuery DatePicker program

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question, why does my code "ignores" the first function while the 2nd function is okay. I have no idea what's going on because the 2nd calendar works fine (prints right date in the console while the first one outputs number "1";) someone please help. Thanks

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bluemilkyh/qwe5h2tr/19/)

```js
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["../widgets/datepicker"], factory);
  } else {
    factory(jQuery.datepicker);
  }
}(function(datepicker) {

  datepicker.regional.sl = {
    closeText: "Zapri",
    prevText: "&#x3C;Prejšnji",
    nextText: "Naslednji&#x3E;",
    currentText: "Trenutni",
    monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Marec", "April", "Maj", "Junij",
      "Julij", "Avgust", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"
    ],
    monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun",
      "Jul", "Avg", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"
    ],
    dayNames: ["Nedelja", "Ponedeljek", "Torek", "Sreda", "Četrtek", "Petek", "Sobota"],
    dayNamesShort: ["Ned", "Pon", "Tor", "Sre", "Čet", "Pet", "Sob"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Ned", "Pon", "Tor", "Sre", "Čet", "Pet", "Sob"],
    weekHeader: "Teden",
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ""
  };
  datepicker.setDefaults(datepicker.regional.sl);
  return datepicker.regional.sl;
}));

$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = ["21.05.2002"];

  function DisableDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date);
    return [dates.indexOf(string) == -1];
  }


  $('#date1').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date);
      return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    },
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
      var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      if (newDate) {
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
      }
      $('#date2').datepicker('setDate', newDate).datepicker('option', 'minDate', newDate);
    }
  });
});
(function(factory) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["../widgets/datepicker"], factory);
  } else {
    factory(jQuery.datepicker);
  }
}(function(datepicker) {

  datepicker.regional.sl = {
    closeText: "Zapri",
    prevText: "&#x3C;Prejšnji",
    nextText: "Naslednji&#x3E;",
    currentText: "Trenutni",
    monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Marec", "April", "Maj", "Junij",
      "Julij", "Avgust", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"
    ],
    monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun",
      "Jul", "Avg", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"
    ],
    dayNames: ["Nedelja", "Ponedeljek", "Torek", "Sreda", "Četrtek", "Petek", "Sobota"],
    dayNamesShort: ["Ned", "Pon", "Tor", "Sre", "Čet", "Pet", "Sob"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Ne", "Po", "To", "Sr", "Če", "Pe", "So"],
    weekHeader: "Teden",
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ""
  };
  datepicker.setDefaults(datepicker.regional.sl);

  return datepicker.regional.sl;

}));


$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = ["21.05.2002"];

  function DisableDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date);
    return [dates.indexOf(string) == -1];
  }

  $('#date2').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date);
      return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    }

  });

});
var zacetek = 1;
var konec;

function myFunction2(val) {
  zacetek = val;

  zacetek = zacetek.split(".").reverse().join("/");

  console.log(zacetek);

  if (konec != undefined) {
    var razlika = ((new Date(konec) - new Date(zacetek)) / 86400000);
    document.getElementById("price").value = razlika;

  }
}

function myFunction1(val) {
  konec = val;
  konec = konec.split(".").reverse().join("/");
  console.log(konec);

  if (zacetek != undefined) {
    var razlika = ((new Date(konec) - new Date(zacetek)) / 86400000);
    document.getElementById("price").value = razlika;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">

    <label for="date"><b>Arrival</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Arrival date" id="date1" name="date1" onchange="myFunction2(this.value)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="date2"><b>Deprature</b></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" required id="date2" name="date2" placeholder="deprature" onchange="myFunction1(this.value)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="example-date-input"><b>Price</b></label>
    <input class="form-control bg-white" type="text" id="price" required placeholder="45€/night" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That one is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bluemilkyh/xhfamck3/81/ but the code above is still not working